# railsのモデルを変数名で動的に取得したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

このようにパラメータから動的に渡ってくるモデル名を変数から取得することは出来ますか？

```
#`Test`はモデル名
model_name = "Test"
model_name.all
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby on Railsを使っている場合、`String#constantize`メソッドが使えます。

```rb
'User'.constantize     # => User(id: ingeter, email: string, ...)
'User'.constantize.all # => [#<User id: 2, email: 'foo@example.com', ...]>]
```

また、Ruby on Railsを前提としない場合、`Module#const_get`が使えます。(Railsを前提とするなら`String#constantize`のほうが便利かなと思います
https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Module/i/const_get.html

```rb
Object.const_get(:User)     # => User(id: ingeter, email: string, ...)
Object.const_get(:User).all # => [#<User id: 1, email: 'foo@example.com', ...]>]
```

ただしこれらはモデルに限らず任意のクラスを取得できるため、注意が必要です。

```rb
# Stringクラスが取得できてしまう
'String'.constantize # => String


# ユーザーに見せたくないモデルも取得できてしまう
'SecretModel'.constantize # => SecretModel(id: integer, ...)
```

そのため、事前にユーザーから渡ってきたモデル名をバリデーションした方が良いでしょう。

また、許可するモデル名が少数の場合には、`String#constantize`を使わずに自分で対応を書いても良いかもしれません。

```rb
# caseを使う例
case model_name
when 'User'
  User
when 'Article'
  Article
else
  raise "#{model_name} is not allowed!"
end

# Hashを使う例
MODEL_TABLE = { 'User' => User, 'Article' => Article}

MODEL_TABLE[model_name] || raise("#{model_name} is not allowed!")
```